# How can I decrease x-ray alpha in 3D view?

Tags: 3d-view, interface, customization

[image: xray alpha]

Is there any way I can decrease alpha opacity so the edges in the back are less visible?

Answer (score 4):

Sure there is.
Just use the *X-Ray slider* in the *Viewport Shader menu*

[image]

Comment: The point would be to decrease only backfaces for retopology purpose. I see there is a slight change of color in the back so I thought there myght be a way to reduce it even more

Answer (score 0):

In that cases I normally reduce the far clipping of the viewCam to a small value. That helps to look only on elements that are close.

Comment: I tried that but its pretty confusing

Comment: What do you mean by confusing ? If you explain, I can improve the answer.

Comment: I would like to hide  edges and vertex in the when doing retopology with xray on. As there is already a lighter color to them, maybe there is a way to make it even more lighter